# Why is [spring-web] a synonym for [spring-mvc]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I noticed that [spring-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-web) is considered a synonym of [spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc).  However, something can be about or use Spring Web without involving Spring Web MVC.  As explained in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13533810/1108305:

> `spring-web` provides core HTTP integration, including some handy Servlet filters, Spring HTTP Invoker, infrastructure to integrate with other web frameworks and HTTP technologies e.g. Hessian, Burlap.
>
> `spring-webmvc` is an implementation of Spring MVC. `spring-webmvc` [depends on](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/3.1.3.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.pom) on `spring-web`, thus including it will transitively add `spring-web`. You don't have to add `spring-web` explicitly.
>
> You should depend only on `spring-web` if you don't use Spring MVC but want to take advantage of other web-related technologies that Spring supports.

Another example is the Spring WebFlux project which uses Spring Web without the Spring Web MVC portion.

Can someone educate me why [spring-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-web) is a synonym of [spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc)?  Is it a situation where most Spring Web questions are also Spring Web MVC questions?  Is the set of answerers the same, so it's convenient that they be handled by the same tag?  Finally, why is the synonym relationship this way, and not have [spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) be a synonym for [spring-web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-web) instead?

I'm looking to better understand the synonym process in Stack Exchange.

Looking at "[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)", I think this falls under the category of subsets being considered synonyms:

> In some cases, tags that are subsets of other tags will also be considered synonyms, such as `java-se` for `java`.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it was tag fragmentation. Tag A is very similar to Tag B, and most of the people using Tag B really mean Tag A. The tags seem similar at a glance.

As to why it was created... if nobody makes a Meta post, there's no telling. It was suggested by a prolific user in the tag, however, but there's no way to tell who voted it into existence.

If you feel the synonym was made in error, I would suggest making a different Meta post making a case for why you feel they need to be separate tags, and the community will express their opinion. I would suggest you make something like [spring-web-tools] to avoid confusion.